# Why does golang compiler think the variable is declared but not used?

Tags: go

I am a newbee to golang, and I write a program to test io package:

```
func main() {
    readers := []io.Reader{
         strings.NewReader("from string reader"),
         bytes.NewBufferString("from bytes reader"),
    }

    reader := io.MultiReader(readers...)
    data := make([]byte, 1024)

    var err error
    //var n int

    for err != io.EOF {
        n, err := reader.Read(data)
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", data[:n])
    }
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

The compile error is "err declared and not used". But I think I have used err in for statement. Why does the compiler outputs this error?

Comment: You could also remove almost all of that code by just using `n, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, io.MultiReader(readers...)` (and the `os.Exit(0)` at the end is unnecessary)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `err` inside the for is shadowing the `err` outside the for, and it's not being used (the one inside the for). This happens because you are using the short variable declaration (with the `:=` operator) which declares a new `err` variable that shadows the one declared outside the for.

Comment: I was under the impression that the `:=` short declaration operator, when used on multiple values, let you use some of them for pre-declared variables as long as at least one was being newly declared.  Why in this case doesn't it reuse the `err` declared earlier if that's the case?

Comment: @thomasrutter because those declarations are in different blocks

Comment: Thanks, I seem to have to frequently make another `var` declaration above a call instead of using short declaration `:=` in order to assign to both an error and a variable in a parent block.