# Assign different struct to variable in If-else block in golang

Tags: go

I want to do something like this

```
type Struct1 {
    str1 string
}
type Struct2{
    int1 int
}

if something {
    someVar := Struct1{str1:''}
} else {
    someVar := Struct2{int1:1}
}

somefunc(someVar)
```

I know I can't declare c inside of one block and then access it outside.

I tried something like this

```
type Struct1 {
    str1 string
}
type Struct2{
    int1 int
}

someVar := Struct2{b:1}
if something {
    someVar := Struct1{a:''}
}

somefunc(c)
```

It gives an error- `Cannot assign Struct1 to c(type Struct2)`

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does golang compiler think the variable is declared but not used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626933/why-does-golang-compiler-think-the-variable-is-declared-but-not-used)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, use an `interface{}`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Struct1 struct {
    a string
}

type Struct2 struct {
    b int
}

func main() {
    var c interface{}
    if true {
        c = Struct1{a: ""}
    } else {
        c = Struct2{b: 1}
    }
    fmt.Printf("type %T", c)
}
// Print:
// type main.Struct1
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Z1cT9qjFmfU

Comment: Still, I would recommend to use custom interface (`type CustomStructInterface{}`) instead of an empty one

Comment: @BohdanKostko indeed. In sake of simplicity I use an empty interface.